# How to add a new item to an object at a specific position with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

Initially, I have such an object

There is more data in it, I missed it

```
"Citizens": [

            {
                "_id": "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Karl",
                "city_id": "1",
                "groups": []
            },
          ]
```

After passing through it in this cycle

```
                       for(let i = 0; i < objTmp[0]["Citizens"].length; i++){
                            for(let j = 0; j < citiesAll[0]["Cities"].length; j++){
                                if(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].id == citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j].id) {

           
                                  objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].city = citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j];


                                }       
                            }
                        }
```

I add a city object from another object to it

I get such an object

"Citizens":
[

```
        {
            "city": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Moscow",
                "data": "10000000"
            },
            "_id": "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Karl",
            "city_id": "1",
            "groups": []
        },
```

]

Question?

How can I add city not to the beginning, as shown here, but to the end?

Comment: Object properties don't have an order.  It's not like an array.

Comment: They do have an order, though it is not always enforced. see: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: objects is really out of order,  but there must be a way to add city to the end?

Comment: There is not a way to add it to the end.  It's the same object, regardless if the city is in the beginning or the end or the middle.

Comment: Working on a solution now. Stay tuned...

Comment: @Brandon McConnell, thanks expect

Comment: Posted my fully explanation and examples. Please consider accepting my answer if this answers your question and works for you

Comment: @Brandon McConnell, Thank you very cool

Comment: @ Brandon McConnell  How to make this construct work in nested loops?

Comment: @ Brandon McConnell the code does not work because citiesAll [0] ["Cities"] has many objects

Comment: @Cooler-cpu could you post the entire code for both objects? My solutions do use nested loops, just nested array method loops. I'll add examples for both of my solutions using classic and `for..of` loops as well. I just need the full data for both objects you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roshan mentioned, key orders aren't reliable in JS and really shouldn't be relied upon. If you need to maintain key order, I suggest using a map.

Here are examples of all both (including the unreliable object route):

## 1. As an Object

Because object keys have no inherent order, this may not look correct if you run it in your browser console and expand your object, but if you run the snippet below, you'll see the correct, expected order in your console. To **ensure** the desired order, use a map, explained further down in section 2.

#### 1.1. As an Object using nested array-method loops

```js
const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

objTmp[0]["Citizens"].forEach((citizen, i) => citiesAll[0]["Cities"].find(city => city.id && citizen.id && city.id === citizen.id && (objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = { ...citizen, city: { ...city } } )))

console.log(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0]);
```

#### 1.2. As an Object using nested `for` loops

```js
const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

for (let i = 0; i < objTmp[0]["Citizens"].length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < citiesAll[0]["Cities"].length; j++) {
        if (objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].id && citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j].id && objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].id === citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j].id) {
            objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = { ...objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i], city: { ...citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j] } };
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0]);
```

#### 1.3. As an Object using nested `for..of` loops

```js
const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

{
    let i = 0;
    for (citizen of objTmp[0]["Citizens"]) {
        let j = 0;
        for (city of citiesAll[0]["Cities"]) {
            if (city.id && citizen.id && city.id === citizen.id) {
                objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = { ...citizen, city: { ...city } };
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

console.log(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0]);
```

## 2. As a Map

This one you'll need to run in your browser's console since StackOverflow's console cannot print JS Map data.

#### 2.1. As a Map using nested array-method loops

```js
// I am only using this replacer function to support logging the result Map data to the console properly. This function is not require for production-use.
const replacer = (a,e) => e instanceof Map?{dataType:"Map",value:Array.from(e.entries())}:e;

const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

objTmp[0]["Citizens"].forEach((citizen, i) => (objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = new Map(Object.entries(citizen)), citiesAll[0]["Cities"].find(city => city.id && objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id') && city.id === objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id') && (objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].set('city', { ...city })))));

console.log(JSON.stringify(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0], replacer, 2));
```

#### 2.2. As a Map using nested `for` loops

```js
// I am only using this replacer function to support logging the result Map data to the console properly. This function is not require for production-use.
const replacer = (a,e) => e instanceof Map?{dataType:"Map",value:Array.from(e.entries())}:e;

const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

for (let i = 0; i < objTmp[0]["Citizens"].length; i++) {
    objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = new Map(Object.entries(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i]));
    for (let j = 0; j < citiesAll[0]["Cities"].length; j++) {
        if (citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j].id && objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id') && citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j].id === objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id')) {
            objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].set('city', { ...citiesAll[0]["Cities"][j] });
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0], replacer, 2));
```

#### 2.3. As a Map using nested `for..of` loops

```js
// I am only using this replacer function to support logging the result Map data to the console properly. This function is not require for production-use.
const replacer = (a,e) => e instanceof Map?{dataType:"Map",value:Array.from(e.entries())}:e;

const objTmp = [{ Citizens: [{ _id: "6070be28c98d5a0ea88f131c", id: 1, name: "Karl", city_id: "1", groups: [] }]}];
const citiesAll = [{ Cities: [{ id: 1, name: "Moscow", data: "10000000" }]}];

{
    let i = 0;
    for (citizen of objTmp[0]["Citizens"]) {
        objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i] = new Map(Object.entries(citizen));
        let j = 0;
        for (city of citiesAll[0]["Cities"]) {
            if (city.id && objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id') && city.id === objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].get('id')) {
                objTmp[0]["Citizens"][i].set('city', { ...city });
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objTmp[0]["Citizens"][0], replacer, 2));
```

Comment: How to make this construct work in nested loops?

Comment: @Cooler-cpu I've updated my solution to include examples of classic `for` loops and `for..of` loops in addition to the array `forEach()` method loops. Please review and try each. Keep in mind that maps will retain order reliably, while objects will not. In order to test the Map solutions (2.1, 2.2, and 2.2), you will need to run the code in your console, since StackOverflow's does not currently support logging map data to its built-in console.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with the other answer(s) providing methods of ordering object keys.

My answer: don't do that. Attempting to order the keys of a JavaScript object is poor practice and is anti-semantic. People reading your code either will be confused or will rightly assume it's full of bugs.

I fully recognize that the keys [will have a de-facto order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/23202095#23202095) but I'm offering the *opinion* that you shouldn't rely on it.

Use maps or tuples or something else built to have an ordering.

Comment: My answer is the only other answer at this point, and I specifically said not to re-order Object keys and to use a Map instead, which I provided specific guidelines and examples, so I'm not sure which other answer(s) you're referring to.